# Jmeter script for switching user lists

Tags: jmeter

I have two data sets which contains teacher list and a student list,
Lets say total 30 students and two teachers and 15 assigned to one teacher and other 15 assigned to second teacher,
And I want to write a Jmeter script to below scenario,

1. login with first 15 students
2. Then login as the first teacher
3. Then again login with the second 15 students
4. Then login with the second teacher,

What is the best approach for this

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should put the threads representing different groups of business or logical users under separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

So you will need 1 Thread Group with 15 threads for students and another Thread Group with 1 thread for teacher. The credentials can be provided using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

If you want first login with 15 users and only after that login with 1 teacher you can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) for implementing such synchronization.